# Arrays.asList().contains() on Double vs double arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a double array `doubleArray1`. I tried a `Arrays.asList().contains()` operation as shown below

```
double doubleArray1 [] = {1D,2D,3D};
if(Arrays.asList(doubleArray1).contains(1D)) {
    System.out.println("hello-1");
}
```

It does not print anything. Then I made it a Double array

```
Double doubleArray1 [] = {1D,2D,3D};        
if(Arrays.asList(doubleArray1).contains(1D)) {
    System.out.println("hello-1");
}
```

It prints `hello-1`.

Could someone explain why this difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first call to `Arrays.asList` is actually returning a `List<double[]>` - it's autoboxing the argument, because a `double[]` isn't a `T[]`... generics don't allow for primitive types as type arguments.

If you want to convert a `double[]` into a `List<Double>`, you either need to do it manually or use a third-party library to do it. For example:

```
public List<Double> toList(double[] doubles) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(doubles.length);
    for (double x : doubles) {
        list.add(x);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that unlike `Arrays.asList` any subsequent changes to the array will *not* be reflected in the list or vice versa - it's a copy, not a view.

Answer (score 0):

Generic allows to use class type not primitive type. Hence while comparing this with primitive it does not give you the desire out put but class type gives you the result.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jon's answer: `asList` takes a vararg (variable arity) parameter list, and vararg parameters don't autobox the way one might expect.  A simple case that doesn't involve generics:

```
public void foo(Double... x) { whatever }

double[] doubleArray1 = {1D,2D,3D};

foo(doubleArray1);  // error
```

gives the error `argument type double[] does not conform to vararg element type Double`.  The same applies to `asList`; what happens here is that since `Arrays.asList` is generic and you haven't explicitly given it the generic type, it will pick whatever works; `Double` doesn't work (for the same reasons the `foo` call won't compile), and `double[]` does work.  This expression, where you explicitly give it the generic parameter, will give you the same error at compile time:

```
Arrays.<Double>asList(doubleArray1).contains(1D)
```